# Apple's TestFlight and Certificates

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, testflight, code-signing-certificate

I recently did some work for a team project and I am trying to use Apple's TestFlight to Submit a new build for an existing app on iTunes Connect for testing, but I got stuck with certificates and provisioning profiles.

**What I have Done so Far**

- Although I was an enrolled iOS developer already (I have my own apps on the AppStore), I gave to the Team Agent a different e-mail address as Apple requested. With this e-mail address I was invited by the Team Agent to iTunes Connect and also to the Member Center and I enrolled again as an iOS developer.
- Afterwards, since I wanted to use Apple's TestFlight, instead of requesting a Developer Certificate through Member Center, I walked to the Team Agent, provided him with my CSR and asked him to prepare a Distribution Certificate for me, which he then sent me.
- After installing this Distribution Certificate on my XCode, I still couldn't Validate the app because I did not have enough privileges. Downloading and installing existing provisioning profiles from the Member Center did not help either.

**My Questions**

1. What should I do in order to have enough privileges to Validate and Submit the build on iTunes (and proceed with using Apple's TestFlight)?
2. Do I need both a Developer's Certificate and a Distribution Certificate in order to be able to upload a build for testing on iTunes Connect? Isn't the Distribution Certificate enough?

Any help will be deeply appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: 2. (About second point) First you could try update your certificates in Xcode 6 - Preferences - Accounts - View Details and select Reload (above left button with circle arrow)... this will update your certificates.

Comment: About the first point, you must have a version created inside itunesConnect to make a validation and then submit the version for test flight

Comment: Hi Beto, thanks for the suggestions. What do you mean I must "have a version created inside itunesConnect"?

Comment: Hello, if you want a validate the program, you must create inside itunesconnect a register for a new version of your program. You must create the register for 1.0 (whatever version) before than a validate, because this is part of the validation process.

Comment: Hi @nosuic, could you make a validation of your program?

Answer (score 7):

1. > What should I do in order to have enough privileges to Validate and Submit the build on iTunes (and proceed with using Apple's TestFlight)?

   To upload binary you need to login with acount that has role `Technical` or `Admin`. More about Role & Responsibilities on [Apple Documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/UsingiTunesConnect/UsingiTunesConnect.html)
2. > Do I need both a Developer's Certificate and a Distribution Certificate in order to be able to upload a build for testing on iTunes Connect? Isn't the Distribution Certificate enough?

   In order to upload binary to iTunes Connect (no matter for releases or Beta testing trought TestFlight) you need to sign binary with **`Distribution Certificate & Provision Profile`**

Comment: Hi skywinder, I am having similar issues with testFlight and certificates. I have an ios developer certificate. The team agent sent me a distribution certificate without a private key (.cer extension). I having No "iOS Distribution" signing certificate matching team ID "team_id" with a private key was found. error every time I relate my provision profile. Is private key of distribution profile required to create-sign-upload a build for testing on TestFlight?

Comment: @SinanGoker it was too long time ago, I don't remeber, sorry

Comment: I have found and imported private key of "iOS Distribution" to solve the issue.